# Changes to X11 Desktop Forwarding over SSH?

Tags: ssh, x11

Has anyone had luck using X11 desktop forwarding over SSH since Jammy Jellyfish (22.04.2)? Up until about a year ago I used this to render the full GUI desktop from my headless Raspberry Pi. When I now try using [X11 Forwarding for Desktop over SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566836/551670) I don't get switched over to virtual terminal 8 (or any other VT), but instead after entering `sudo xinit -- :1 &` I get an error:

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: connection to X server lost
X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

The log file repeats the error output above. X11 forwarding is enabled on the RPI in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Could Wayland affect this or has X changed somehow? I haven't found any indications it in the man pages or any sites.

Comment: Maybe you can just not run the `xinit` command and go directly for the `ssh -X ...` command